# Firebase update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I am relatively new on firebase. I want to update existing data on my firebase database. I have UITableView and UITableViewCells on my Xcode project, when user touch (tap gesture), for example a outlet on cell view, I want to update Firebase Database but this could be any cell on tableview. How to find this cell which user touched on screen, on firebase database and update its messageVoteScore value. There are assigned keys but my cells do not know those keys,
 I could not figure it out how to match them.(Database/Messages/{"sender": "email"},{"messageBody":"text.."},{"messageVoteScore":"100"}

```
@objc func voteUpTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Update score //
    self.messageVoteScore.text = String(Int(self.messageVoteScore.text!)! + 1 )

    //observeSingleEventOfType listens for a tap by the current user.
    Database.database().reference().child("Messages").observe(.value){
        (snapshot) in

        if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String : String] {
            print(snapshotValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your code? For instance where does this function reside? If it's in your `UITableViewCell` class then presumably you could have a reference to the cell's Post object in there that you could pass to firebase update method.

Comment: This method is in my UITableViewCell class yes. @ChrisEdgington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing class objects to your cell? If so you could use a protocol/delegate for this. A UITableView Cell is a View and shouldn't function as a controller. your UITableViewController should be updating firebase.

you should start by adding something like this to the top of your Cell class:

```
    protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate: class {
        func thingDidDo(object: Object, text: String...) //object is the class object you are changing.
```

then add the delegate to your properties:

```
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewCellDelegate?
```

then add the IBAction:

```
    @IBAction func thingDidDo(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.thingDidDo(object: object, text: textView.text...)
    }
```

Now back to your viewController Class:

In your "cellForRowAt" write in the delegate:

```
    cell.delegate = self
```

then add an extension

```
    extension MyTableViewController: MyTableViewCellDelegate {

       func thingDidDo(object: Object, text: String) {
          Do whatever you want with object, text...
       }
```

Not sure what kind of function you are trying to perform so I made this as generic as I could

Comment: Hi @Sente Thanks for your answer. i have a TableViewController class for chat feed line and I declared it as delegate for tableview also datasource. On the other hand, I have TableViewCellController and this method I shared inside of it. Also my object is like message class I created just have 3 instance variables like sender, messageBody, voteScore

Comment: basically, this description creates your own delegate. this is the protocol. Then the tableViewController can perform tasks on behalf of the tableViewCell.

Comment: did you implement it?

Comment: Sorry for being late @Sente, it is still not solving my problem. I cant update spesific data on firebase. I cant reach id of spesific node on database. :(

Comment: well that sounds like a firebase problem then