# ReloadData with Protocol on custom cell with Collectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I attempted a bunch of answers on here with no luck.

I am attempting to reload my collectionview within my custom cell after fetching data from firebase. I am unable to even get the print statement to show from the custom cell. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

On my ViewController I have the following delegate and call, I made a button to test to see if the delegate print statement on my custom cell will appear but no luck.

```
protocol DiscoverControllerDelegate {
func didFetchData()
}

class DiscoverController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "cellId"
let headerId = "headerId"
let database = FirebaseData.sharedInstance
var delegate: DiscoverControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    title = "Discover"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(CategoriesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.register(HeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Refresh", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(reloadData))
    database.retrieveData {
        print("fetching data")
        self.delegate?.didFetchData()
    }

}

@objc func reloadData () {
    print("attemping to reload")
   self.delegate?.didFetchData()
}
```

*edit to add on my override init
On my custom cell:

```
class CategoriesCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, DiscoverControllerDelegate  {

let itemCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

    return collectionView
}()

func didFetchData() {
    print("RELOADING NOW!")
    itemCollectionView.reloadData()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    itemCollectionView.dataSource = self
    itemCollectionView.delegate = self
    itemCollectionView.register(ItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    itemCollectionView.reloadData()

    createLayout()

}
```

Comment: You need to show the `cellForItemAt` method for the collection view inside the DiscoverController so that we can see how the cells CategoriesCells are setup.  Also how many cells are in the UICollectionView inside the DiscoverController because only one will ever be the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Many things wrong here. The reason `"RELOADING NOW!"` never logs is because you never set the delegate in your view controller. If you inspect `self.delegate` in `DiscoverController` it is probably nil. However, your entire setup right now seems flawed unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing.

What does your UI look like? Why does `CategoriesCell` have a `UICollectionView` property? It's `itemCollectionView` property doesn't even have a datasource or delegate set and its not an `@IBOutlet` yet you're calling `reloadData()` on it. Not sure what it's even displaying or what you're tyring to do.

I feel like there is probably a lot more wrong here than just a single thing. You probably want to go through some `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` tutorials to learn about delegates and datasources in iOS.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding. I have added the override Init on my edit. I have set the itemCollectionView datasource and delegate there.

I followed an video from Let's Build That App youtube channel (The App Store), and he did it this way to have horizontal scrolling CV and vertical sections.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about collection view but I use similar protocol structures with a table view. They are not much different. your protocol should be in the cell class not in the controller. 
I've gone through the steps for a table view in the following post:

[Firebase update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134507/firebase-update/48138964?noredirect=1#comment83323214_48138964)

Maybe you can adapt it for your needs...